# cast to decimal in linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
var data = await dbContext.Set<OwnerData>().FromSqlRaw(@"
                SELECT [OWP].[OwnerProfileId],                    
                SELECT [OWP].[Email],
                FROM [user].[OwnerProfile] AS [OWP]
                CAST(ISNULL([OWB].[CustomBalance], 0) AS decimal(18, 3)) AS [CustomBalance]
                INNER JOIN [user].[OwnerBalance] AS [OWB] ON [OWB].[OwnerProfileId] = [OWP].[OwnerProfileId]
                WHERE [ThirdPartyRefId] = {0}", ownerProfileId)
               .ToListAsync();
```

I rewrite this into linq expression like this

```
 var data = await _context.Set<OwnerProfile>()
                .Include(x => x.OwnerBalances)                
                .Where(x => x.ThirdPartyRefId== ownerProfileId)
                .ToListAsync();
```

not sure how to set this

```
CAST(ISNULL([OWB].[CustomBalance], 0) AS decimal(18, 3)) AS [CustomBalance]
```

into lambda query

Comment: What's the type of the `CustomBalance` property of your entity class? And why don't you just stick with raw SQL?

Comment: `decimal` in .NET has no configurable precision or scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having class definitions its a little difficult to give you specifics, but you could try to add something like:

```
var data = await _context.Set<OwnerProfile>()
                .Include(x => x.OwnerBalances)                
                .Where(x => x.ThirdPartyRefId== ownerProfileId)
                .Select(x => new 
                 {
                    x.Prop1,
                    x.Prop2,
                    CustomerBalance = x.CustomerBalance.Value != null ? x.CustomerBalance.Value : 0
                 })
                .ToListAsync();
```

You may be able to move the select statement outside the query too:

```
var newData = data.Select(x => new 
              {
                 x.Prop1,
                 x.Prop2,
                 CustomerBalance = x.CustomerBalance.Value != null ? x.CustomerBalance.Value : 0
              })
```

You might be able to use conditional access in the 2nd version, but possibly not in the first.